# What are the different collections supported by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

What are The different collections supported by Hibernate like

1. List -- > ArrayList,LinkedList etc
2. Set --> Treeset,HashSet etc
3. Map --> HashMap etc

And tell me which are collections not supported and how to achieve them?

Comment: Why don't you focus on what's your requirement and see if Hibernate supports that or not, instead of classifying all the existing Collections as supported or not?

Comment: Maybe this link helps you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505874/hibernate-best-collection-type-to-use-bag-idbag-set-list-map

Comment: What is your issue/problem. Then you can decide which one to use.

Comment: Use Hashset for collection related to hibernate

Answer (score 1):

According to the Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html):

> *" The persistent collections injected by Hibernate behave like `HashMap`, `HashSet`, `TreeMap`, `TreeSet` or `ArrayList`, depending on the interface type."*

Note that they *behave like* those classes, but they are actually Hibernate-specific collection classes.

---

> And tell me which are collections not supported and how to achieve them?

In the sense that you mean: 1) any class not on the list above, and 2) you can't unless you are willing to modify the core Hibernate codebase.

Comment: collection not supported an declared in entity are serialised in binary file. Single DB field is unreadable, but data are not lost

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate only support Collection Types that extends from the interfaces Set, Map, and Collection. For use this collections do you have to create a variable of the supertype(inteface class);

Example:

```
class Pojo{
        Map map;

        public Pojo(){
         map = new HashMap<>();
       }

}
```

Comment: I see in other post that Hivernate have an attribute to set the collection type (collection-type) but i can't confirm that.